# folland, computation in proof of theorem 1.18 (inner regularity of borel measure on R)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[folland theorem 1-18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quxZH.png)

for the inner regularity proof: to show $\mu(E)$ is a tight upper bound on $\mu(K)$, the first equality folland uses is
$$
\mu (K) = \mu(E) - \mu(E \cap U).
$$

i'm able to show it by
\begin{align*}
\mu(E) = \mu(E \cap U) + \mu(E \setminus U)
= \mu(E \cap U) + \mu(\overline{E} \setminus U^c)
= \mu(E \cap U) + \mu(K).
\end{align*}

but what's the intuition behind this equality? at first i thought it's because maybe $\mu(\overline{E}) = \mu(E)$, so then
$$
\mu(K) = \mu(\overline{E} \setminus U) = \mu(E \setminus U).
$$
but this isn't true in general, i.e. $$m(\overline{Q}) = m(R) = \infty \neq 0 = m(Q),$$
and you can just intersect the above with $I$ to get a bounded counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the equality as $\mu(K)+\mu(E\cap U)=\mu(E)$ which we prove by applying the usual property of measures (additivity of disjoint unions). To do this we need that $K\cap (E\cap U)=\emptyset $ and $K\cup (E\cap U)=E$ but this is true because $K$ is precisely the points of $E$ that are not contained in $U$. This point is a bit confusing because $K$ is defined as $\overline{E}\setminus U$, but remember that $U$ contains all of the points of $\overline{E}$ that are not in $E$ so we are removing all such points and thus are left with $E$ minus whatever else in $U$ we have to take away. It may enlightening to draw these sets for a simple example like $E=(0,1)$.